# How to run raspbian jessie on emulator?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

i have been working on raspberry pi and i have been able to install and configure raspbian jessie on my raspbian pi zero but i am not able to find any raspbian jessie emulator to run on my pc. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QEMU that emulates ARM chipsets, such as that found in the Raspberry Pi.

Follow [this guide](http://dbakevlar.com/2015/08/emulating-a-raspberry-pi-on-virtualbox/) for Windows!

Comment: Thanks mate. rate my  question too. :)